# scraping h3 from div using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'd like to scrape, using Python 3.6, H3 titles from within DIV - from the page:

https://player.bfi.org.uk/search/rentals?q=&sort=title&page=1

Note that the page number changes, increment of 1.

I'm struggling to return or identify the title.

```
from requests import get
url = 'https://player.bfi.org.uk/search/rentals?q=&sort=title&page=1'
response = get(url)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
type(html_soup)
movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'card card--rentals')
print(type(movie_containers))
print(len(movie_containers))
```

I've tried looping through them also:

```
for dd in page("div.card__content"):
    print(div.select_one("h3.card__title").text.strip())
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

I'm expecting results of Title of each film from each page, including link to the film. Eg. https://player.bfi.org.uk/rentals/film/watch-akenfield-1975-online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is loading content via xhr to another url so you are missing this. You can mimic that xhr POST request the page uses and alter post json sent. If you change `size` you get more results.

```
import requests

data = {"size":1480,"from":0,"sort":"sort_title","aggregations":{"genre":{"terms":{"field":"genre.raw","size":10}},"captions":{"terms":{"field":"captions"}},"decade":{"terms":{"field":"decade.raw","order":{"_term":"asc"},"size":20}},"bbfc":{"terms":{"field":"bbfc_rating","size":10}},"english":{"terms":{"field":"english"}},"audio_desc":{"terms":{"field":"audio_desc"}},"colour":{"terms":{"field":"colour"}},"mono":{"terms":{"field":"mono"}},"fiction":{"terms":{"field":"fiction"}}},"min_score":0.5,"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match_all":{}},"must_not":[],"should":[],"filter":{"term":{"pillar.raw":"rentals"}}}}}
r = requests.post('https://search-es.player.bfi.org.uk/prod-films/_search', json = data).json()
for film in r['hits']['hits']:
    print(film['_source']['title'], 'https://player.bfi.org.uk' + film['_source']['url'])
```

The actual result count for `rentals` is in the json, `r['hits']['total']`,  so you can do an initial request, starting with a number much higher than you expect,  check if another request is needed, and then gather any extra by altering the `from` and `size` to mop up any outstanding.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

initial_count = 10000
results = []

def add_results(r):
    for film in r['hits']['hits']:
        results.append([film['_source']['title'], 'https://player.bfi.org.uk' + film['_source']['url']])

with requests.Session() as s:
    data = {"size": initial_count,"from":0,"sort":"sort_title","aggregations":{"genre":{"terms":{"field":"genre.raw","size":10}},"captions":{"terms":{"field":"captions"}},"decade":{"terms":{"field":"decade.raw","order":{"_term":"asc"},"size":20}},"bbfc":{"terms":{"field":"bbfc_rating","size":10}},"english":{"terms":{"field":"english"}},"audio_desc":{"terms":{"field":"audio_desc"}},"colour":{"terms":{"field":"colour"}},"mono":{"terms":{"field":"mono"}},"fiction":{"terms":{"field":"fiction"}}},"min_score":0.5,"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match_all":{}},"must_not":[],"should":[],"filter":{"term":{"pillar.raw":"rentals"}}}}}
    r = s.post('https://search-es.player.bfi.org.uk/prod-films/_search', json = data).json()
    total_results = int(r['hits']['total'])
    add_results(r)

    if total_results > initial_count :
        data['size'] = total_results - initial_count
        data['from'] = initial_count
        r = s.post('https://search-es.player.bfi.org.uk/prod-films/_search', json = data).json()
        add_results(r)

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Title', 'Link'])
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue you are having is not actually with finding the `div` - I think you are doing that correctly. However, when you try to access the website with

```py
from requests import get
url = 'https://player.bfi.org.uk/search/rentals?q=&sort=title&page=1'
response = get(url)
```

the response doesn't actually include all the content you see in the browser. You can check that this is the case with `'card' in response == False`. This is most likely because after the website is loaded, all the cards are loaded via javascript, therefore just loading the basic content in with `requests` library is not sufficient to get all the information you want to scrape.

I suggest you maybe try looking at how the website loads all the cards - Network tab in the browser dev tools might help.

Comment: Thank you. OK. Will take a look at this.